# jQuery change height on overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a div and its height is fixed to 100px right now.

but its data is not static and a user can add as much data as he wants, i dont want scroll bars and it should get resized to data contained in it(height only) is there any css property to achieve this except than min-height as it doesnot work on IE.

the div may have multiple children and i am thinking to do something that doesnt involve calculating change of height of all children

thanks

Comment: do you need to mention a minimum height if there is nothing in the div?

Comment: @sv_in - yes minimum is required

Comment: read [this](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/min-height-hack)  and [this one](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to do using jQuery only calculated height of children and set it parent, css hacks dint helped

Answer (score 1):

`height` in IE6 is essentially `min-height` anyway. If you don't have a problem using quick hacks -

```
div.blah {
    _height:100px;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

...otherwise, tuck it in some Conditional Comments so you can sleep at night.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">div.blah { height:100px; }</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @Varun, The first property `_height` works only IE6 where `height` property works like min-height. For other browsers, `min-height` is the way to go

Comment: so its back to basic i have to perform JS actions on IE then, which dont want

Comment: @Varun: There's no JS in my answer, only a minor CSS hack for IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `height:auto;overflow:visible;`. This will make the `<div>` autosize itself.

Comment: cant give height as auto, need some predefined structure

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow:visible; height:100px;
```

Should work, no?

Comment: will result in overlapping with other parts of page

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Hope I helped.